# Ansible: register output of command, parse it, give it to container as environment variable: Variable not defined

Tags: docker, variables, ansible

I have an ansible playbook as follows (with irrelevant info stripped):

```
  tasks:
    - name: get public_ip4 output
      shell: curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4 
      register: public_ip4
    - debug: var=public_ipv4.stdout
    - name: Create docker_pull
      template: <SNIP>
    - name: Pull containers
      command: "sh /root/pull_agent.sh"
    - name: (re)-create the agent
      docker_container:
        name: agent
        image: registry.gitlab.com/project_agent
        state: started
        exposed_ports: 8889
        published_ports: 8889:8889
        recreate: yes
        env:
          host_machine: public_ipv4.stdout
```

The target machine is an AWS EC2 instance. The purpose is to get its public IPv4 address and give it as an environment variable to a container. The container has a Python instance, Agent, that will use os.environ.get(host_machine) to thus access the IPv4 address of the EC2 instance.

The output from the debug logs is (with irrelevant info removed and the ipv4 address replaced with  ):

```
PLAY [swarm_manager_main] ******************************************************

TASK [get public_ip4 output] ***************************************************
 [WARNING]: Consider using the get_url or uri module rather than running
'curl'.  If you need to use command because get_url or uri is insufficient you
can add 'warn: false' to this command task or set 'command_warnings=False' in
ansible.cfg to get rid of this message.
changed: [tm001.stackl.io] => {"changed": true, "cmd": "curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4", "delta": "0:00:00.013260", "end": "2019-08-02 08:36:26.649844", "rc": 0, "start": "2019-08-02 08:36:26.636584", "stderr": "  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current\n                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed\n\r  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0\r100    12  100    12    0     0   2600      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  3000", "stderr_lines": ["  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current", "                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed", "", "  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0", "100    12  100    12    0     0   2600      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  3000"], "stdout": "<HIDDEN>", "stdout_lines": ["52.210.80.33"]}

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [tm001.stackl.io] => {
    "public_ipv4.stdout": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!: 'public_ipv4' is undefined"
}

TASK [Create docker_pull] ******************************************************
<SNIP>
TASK [Pull containers] *********************************************************
<SNIP>

TASK [(re)-create the agent] ********************************************
changed: <SNIP> ["host_machine=public_ipv4.stdout", <SNIP>
```

I don't understand why the public_ipv4 variable is not used correctly. I've tried multiple things (including setting set_fact or setting a new variable) but to no avail.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo in your playbook: ip4 and ipv4

```
register: public_ip4
debug: var=public_ipv4.stdout
```